# How can i pair images in my DB?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I had a hard time giving this question a title, i hope im clear enough.
Im using PHP & HTML with a MYSQL Database.

See I have a member site, where every new member gets a randomly chosen football player as their avatar. The football player avatar is assigned from a folder named 'avatars'.
Once the user is registered, the avatar is moved to a folder named 'used_avatars'. Every image is named as the football player, because i want to display the name of the chosen player on the users member page.

Here's the real question: I want to add a flag representing the players nationality on the member site. But I have several Brazilian players and only one Brazilian flag. How do i pair my 5 players with the one flag. I was thinking of naming the images "brazil-ronaldo", "brazil-carlos" and then in some way in PHP separating the country from the name and match them with a flag and a avatar. Does this make sense? Is there any better way of doing this?
I guess I need to create a new table in my database that keeps record of flag and avatar match?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please post your code and tell what isn't working correctly.

Comment: Keeping `Football player` details in DB is much better. Details can be more than just country of origin. You can expand the range of details as necessary.

Comment: Instead of moving images to used `Avatar` keep records in DB against MemberIDs by assigning a `UniqueID` for every `Football Player`. It'll save you a lot of space.

Comment: there is no code to post, its a question of how to plan my DB and how i should start my work, I don't need code posted I need advise.

Comment: So i should assign UniqueID to each player and then store info about the player in my DB? It sound like a good way to go. I could keep information about the players nationality as well.

Comment: Do you want me to elaborate on that?

Comment: Well if you have anything more to add please do, but i do think i'm understanding your answer and i will start by adding a player table to my DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

You need a table for players containing field for a nationality id and a table with nationalities with the names for the flags.

This way you can select the player and join the nationality via the id.

All you have to do then is save the player id in the user "profile".

Comment: When you explain it like you do, it makes me wounder why I didn't figure this way out from the beginning. :) So i would need a User-Table, Player-Table and a Nationality-Table?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning a random player avatar for new members, assign a default avatar(cartoon).

1. Members/Users table will have a column `avatar_id`.
2. A table `avatars_history (member_id, avatar_id, order)`. where `order` wil be the sequence in which they were changed. You can have date too if necessary.
3. A table `football_players (player_id, country_id, full_name, dob, world_rank, etc)`.
4. A table `avatars (player_id, avatar_id)` where `avatar_id` is the filename of the picture. Meaning a single player can have multiple pictures.

And keep all avatars(player pictures with unique names) in a single folder.

Comment: This sounds great, when i optimize my amateur site this will be the way to go :)